# Knockout change span visible state on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I would like to show error message on user button click (in case user open page and click on directly just on button).
But Visible state workin just if user edit fields
How to fire methods to change visible state ?

```
<body>
   <input type="text" data-bind="value: can" id="txtcan" />                        
                        <span ID="lblCANerror" data-bind="visible:(viewModel.can()=='')"  class="error">Mesasage 1</span>                    
                                            <input type="text" data-bind="value: login" id="txtusername" />
                        <span ID="lblUsernameError" data-bind="visible:(viewModel.login()=='')" class="error">Mesasage 2</span>

                        <input type="password" data-bind="value: password" name="txtpassword"  />
                        <span ID="lblPasswordError" data-bind="visible:(viewModel.password()=='')" class="error">Mesasage 3</span>

                        <button ID="lnkLogin" data-bind="click: ClickBtn"> Click</button>                

</body>

<script type='text/javascript'>
 var ViewModel = function () {
        this.can = ko.observable();
        this.login = ko.observable();
        this.password = ko.observable();
        this.isValidForm = ko.computed(function () {
            return ($.trim(this.can) != "") && ($.trim(this.login) != "") && ($.trim(this.password) != "");
        }, this);
    this.ClickBtn = function(data, e)
    {
      if (!this.isValidForm()) 
          { 

             e.stopImmediatePropagation();
          }; 
    };
    };

    var viewModel = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);



</script>
  <style type='text/css'>
    .error
{ 
    color: #FF0000;     
}
  </style>
```

I don't want write to write code for change span visible state manually (*like if () then span.show*) is it possible to use just knockoutjs FW ?
I have tried subscribe to event with JQuery but result is the same.

```
 $().ready(function () {
        $("#lnkLogin").click(function (event) {
            if (!viewModel.isValidForm()) {                
                event.preventDefault();
            };    
        })
    });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove user defined error span it is not needed.

**option 1 (recommended)**

1.) import [ko validation js](https://raw.github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/master/Src/knockout.validation.js).

2.)extend validation

```
this.can = ko.observable().extend({required:true});
```

3.)set initial show validation error msg == false

4.) set value == true to show error

[Check this fiddle how to show validation error msg when button click](http://jsfiddle.net/naveenkumarm/VeBSf/)

**Option2**

1.)Add another observable

```
this.showError = ko.observable(false);
```

2.)modify condition

```
 data-bind="visible:(can()=='' && showError())"
```

3.)Changes in click

```
$().ready(function () {
    $("#lnkLogin").click(function (event) {

        //check contions here
        if(!true){
           viewModel.showError(true); // to show error msg
          }

        if (!viewModel.isValidForm()) {                
            event.preventDefault();
        };    
    })
});
```

Comment: I am pretty sure it would be. but by some reason I need to try to solve it in my conditions.